# Hide certain rows in tableview while a current drag session is active?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to hide certain rows when the user has initiated a drag event?

I tried doing it in this delegate and I was able to hide certain rows but then I got really wonky and unexpected behaviour while dragging the row

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem]
```

Comment: Show more code. What behaviour did you observe?

Comment: `UITableViews` conform to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol. With that in mind, here are some methods you could implement. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate#

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the following methods:

`func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(UIScrollView) { // hide whatever rows you want }`

and...

`func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(UIScrollView) { // unhide them }`